# enable js remotely throw maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: react-native

i created a simple react-native app, then can run in ios.
but after i enable "Debug JS Remotely", throw below exception, any idea?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNPQc.png)
"maximum call stack size exceeded
 react-native.js:30758:14
"

the project is created by "react-native init AwesomeProject", no other change.

**this exception only throw by atom starting debugger, that mean, if i use chrome to debug, all fine. may i miss any setting for atom to debug react native app?**

Comment: Is your server running?

Comment: yes,  use 'react-native run-ios' to run the server, it's fine to work with "Disable js remotely".but after i enable, the exception throw

Comment: close all the server and start server with react-native start

Comment: had you enable hot reloading?

Comment: yes, already enable hot reloading, and run with react-native start, got same exception, seem loop at react-native.js getvalue() function.

Comment: disable hot reloading

Answer (score 0):

Replace the method as the one below in ***node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js***

```
     callNativeSyncHook(
    moduleID: number,
    methodID: number,
    params: mixed[],
    onFail: ?(...mixed[]) => void,
    onSucc: ?(...mixed[]) => void,
  ): mixed {
    this.processCallbacks(moduleID, methodID, params, onFail, onSucc);
    const isDebuggingEnabled = (typeof atob !== 'undefined');
    if (!isDebuggingEnabled) {
      return global.nativeCallSyncHook(moduleID, methodID, params);
    }
  }
```

The original solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66583605/11317208

Answer (score -1):

try to start `npm`:

```
npm start
```

and then "Debug JS Remotely"