# React Native Chrome Debugger Error: NativeUIManager.getConstantsForViewManager('Text') threw an exception

Tags: react-native

I'm newly developing in react native.

To start I used `npx react-native init hello_world --template react-native-template-typescript` to create the basic code and then I replaced app.tsx with this code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.helloWorldContainer}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}>Hello, world!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  helloWorldContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

And these are the errors that I get when I am in debug mode:
[image: Error picture]

[image: Error picture]

If I remove the style of the component Text the error disappears.
My question is how can I fix the error while keeping the style in the component Text.
I saw that chrome has a lot of errors, exist another better debugger?

Comment: There is a temporary solution for this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067004/invariant-violation-calling-synchronous-methods-on-native-modules-is-not-suppor/66583605#66583605)

Comment: Hi did you get any solution for this?

Comment: The problem is that google chrome has a different javascript engine that react native for this reason it is preferable to use other debuggers.

Answer (score 3):

As what [Lucas Azambuja Santos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13944932/lucas-azambuja-santos) referred to, it's a bug in `react-native 0.65.*` check out the new issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32197

it should be fixed with 0.66, to workaround downgrade to 0.64.x and rebuild:

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean cleanBuildCache
```