# EXPO + react-native-reanimated debug issue

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated-v2

I've had an app running on Expo SDK 41 and it had some basic usage of `react-native-reanimated@~2.1.0` and debugging worked just fine.

At some stage SDK 41 was deprecated and I was forced to upgrade, so I went for the latest one which is 45.

After the upgrade I can no longer use remote debugging. When I turn on remote debugging, the app crashes with the following error

```
Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome.

Consider providing alternative methods to expose this method in debug mode, e.g. by exposing constants ahead-of-time.
```

and I can't do anything (I can't even turn off remote debugging without clearing expo app data).

The issue seems to be related to react-native-reanimated (current version is 2.8.0)

[image]

Expo [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/) state this:

> The new APIs in react-native-reanimated@2 use React Native APIs that
> are incompatible with Remote JS Debugging. Consequently, you can only
> debug apps using these APIs using Flipper, which is not yet available
> in the Expo managed workflow. You will be unable to use Remote JS
> Debugging if you use the new APIs from Reanimated 2. Remote JS
> Debugging will continue to work if you only use the APIs that were
> also available in Reanimated 1.

Tried to downgrade to `react-native-reanimated@~2.1.0` did not work either.

I must be missing something, because otherwise it seems a bit ridiculous that I'm forced to upgrade SDK which in combination with react-native-reanimated does not allow me to do debug anymore.

Please advise if there is anything I can do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting a question on expo repository, I've got the following [answer](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17957#issuecomment-1166156807) which actually does not solve the remote debugger issue, but gives the same alternative. Basically they suggested to use Hermes engine.

> hi there! this is unfortunate and inconvenient for sure. it's a side
> effect of the direction the ecosystem is moving in - away from
> JavaScript Core and remote debugging in Chrome towards Hermes and
> attaching a debugger to the on-device Hermes engine. Reanimated no
> longer supports remote debugging in Chrome.
> in order to debug JS using Reanimated in SDK 45+ we recommend using Hermes. you can set this up in your app.json as follows:
>
> ```
> {
>   "expo": {
>     "// your other config here": "...",
>     "android": {
>       "jsEngine": "hermes"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> now when you run expo start and launch your app press j and it will launch a Chrome Inspector that will attach directly to the app on
> your device (I suggest upgrading expo-cli to the latest to ensure you
> have this feature). be sure to refer to the "Using Hermes Engine"
> guide for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is what that link to Expo's docs show me at this time:

> Reanimated uses React Native APIs that are incompatible with "Remote JS
> Debugging" for JavaScriptCore. In order to use a debugger with your app with
> react-native-reanimated, you will need to use the Hermes JavaScript engine and > the JavaScript Inspector for Hermes.

Anyways, this appears to be an issue Reanimated themselves talk about in the [docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/)

The workaround around this for some time has been this code shared in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66583605)

It isn't even a reanimated problem particularly, but an inability of RN to develop using some synchronous features that pertain to debugging.

Anyways, hope this helps you